# Object does not appear when rendered

Tags: rendering, objects, blender-internal-render-engine, camera

I am having a problem to see one of my mesh objects through camera. I have 3 components that I imported from sketch up dad format. They are cup, handle, and saucer.

The outliner looks like this:

[image]

I have a camera and light set up like this:

[image]

When I render the scene the handle and saucer will show, but not the cup body:

[image]

peach_cup_body mesh looks like this under material tab. These are all the same to handle, and saucer.

[image]

Could anyone have an idea why this is happening? Any help will be greatly appreciated it!!
thank you.

Comment: A .blend is always a nice addition, since you may have missed a critical screen shot. Nice work for adding so much information though +1.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of the layers panel?(one after the camera)

Comment: GiantCowFilms:  I think it helps to specify a commonly used service for uploading blend files.  Without that, newer people who are being asked this will search the interface here and see nothing and they will not be able to do it.  Some others will seek out random hosting sites, some of which have adware.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing a blend file I would guess that the peach_cup_body object does not have the correct material assigned.

There are two materials on the object, one is a cycles material which will render the object as blank when rendering with the internal renderer.

Remove the material called 'material' and your object will definitely be using the 'Material.002' material.

Select the material then press the minus(-) button:

[image]

Comment: If this question has helped you then feel free to accept this answer by clicking the tick icon next to the answer. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers